# java scripts on my website running locally but not running on server

Tags: javascript

I have a designed a website and included some java scripts, they run perfectly locally but on uploading to the server, nothing works!! I tried changing the reference to the pages to //http: but still...nothing. I've tried testing on the server with a simple alert text box,it works. I don't understand why the other .js scripts aren't working. please Help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var shutterSettings = {"msgLoading":"L O A D I N G","msgClose":"Click to Close","imageCount":"1"};
</script>
<script src='http://www.broadigital.co.ke/style/newcss/js/shutter-reloaded.js?ver=1.3.3' type='text/javascript' ></script>
<script src='http://www.broadigital.co.ke/style/newcss/js/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2' type='text/javascript' ></script>
<script src='http://www.broadigital.co.ke/style/newcss/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=2.9995' type='text/javascript' ></script>
<script src='http://www.broadigital.co.ke/style/newcss/js/ngg.slideshow.min.js?ver=1.06' type='text/javascript' ></script>
<script src='http://www.broadigital.co.ke/style/newcss/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=3.4.2' type='text/javascript' ></script>
```

Comment: the website is www.broadigital.co.ke

Comment: looks like the jquery file uploaded to the site is broken, try uploading the jquery.js file again and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Check if you uploaded jQuery correctly. The file might have been truncated in the process.

**UPDATE**

Checking your jQuery file, the file truncates on line 6 with these as the last few characters.

```
if(this[0]){var b=f(a,this[0].owne
```

**SOLUTION**

- Re-upload the jQuery file (`jquery.js`) again, or
- Use jQuery CDN:

Change:

```
<script src='http://www.broadigital.co.ke/style/newcss/js/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

To:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: how so? you mean the rest of the file is missing?

Comment: Hey!! Thanks alot!! that was the only problem.it has taken me over a week to figure it out. you are a genius!!!